# selenium/java- java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

I'm running into error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset and I have no idea why :(

I just updated my chromdriver into the same version as my browser and still getting this error. I'm out of ideas.
Code below.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 63488
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jun 25, 2022 6:34:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Jun 25, 2022 6:34:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 103, so returning the closest version found: 102
Jun 25, 2022 6:34:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 103 of 102
Nieoczekiwany bl?d:
Jun 25, 2022 6:34:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the *incompatibility* between the version of the `binaries` you are using as follows:

You have downloaded and used chromedriver=103.0 which got initiated successfully. But your are still using chrome=102

Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v103*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

Supports Chrome `version 103`

***Solution***

*Solution Ensure that:*

Chrome Browser is updated to current chrome=103