# Selenium java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when calling driver.quit();

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I saw these threads:

[java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on Selenium driver.close() or driver.quit() statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303153/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-on-selenium-driver-close-or-driver)

[selenium/java- java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755662/selenium-java-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

But I still don't understand the issue here. Everything is working fine, I get the response and content from the website and when I'm done I call the `driver.quit();` / `driver.close();` and get the exception. If I don't call that `.quit();` I don't get the exception.

I get this exception after I get the web scraping content:

```
2023-01-31T21:28:31.222+01:00  WARN 8400 --- [cHttpClient-1-4] o.a.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler       : onError

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-01-31T21:28:31.229+01:00  WARN 8400 --- [cHttpClient-1-4] o.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket  : Connection reset

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This is the code from the main:

```
        String url = "https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get(url + "Fishsticks");

        WebElement words = driver.findElement(By.className("words"));
        final List<WebElement> wordList = words.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        wordList.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word.getText()));

        // when I remove this I do not get any exceptions
        driver.quit();
```

I use the latest chrome version I just checked, and there are no updates available (Version 109.0.5414.120) and I am using chrome driver version ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 and the latest selenium version 4.8.0

So what is the solution here? I tried to read so many stack threads but have not found any solution

Comment: AFAIK, "connection reset" means the other side already closed the connection for you.  In HTTP, it's normal close the connection immediately after all data is sent (unless "keep alive" is set?), so what you're getting is probably normal.

Comment: @markspace Okay, so what should I do about it? What I understand from this is that I should not call the quit(), is that a better approach to this issue, or better to catch it and do nothing about it? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the same code I have tried and it works fine with no exceptions. Only difference is that I have not added following code `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);`. You do not need to set property when you are using the latest version of selenium(which you are using anyways). Try removing this line and see if it resolves your issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/" + "Fishsticks");
    
    WebElement words = driver.findElement(By.className("words"));
    final List<WebElement> wordList = words.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    wordList.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word.getText()));

    driver.quit();

}
```

Here is the console output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 2732
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
batter
cod
united kingdom
ketchup
herring
whitefish
hake
haddock
pollock
refrigerator
british english
breaded
american english
europe
food processing
supermarket
grilling
tartar sauce
fish
machine
backbone
parents
frozen food
wheel
blade
television commercial
southampton
shallow frying
skin
breadcrumbs
salmon
bone
deep frying
world war ii
gorton's of gloucester
clarence birdseye
store brand
vegetable oil
```

Comment: Do  you mean you executed your program with out the `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");` line?

Comment: Yes @undetectedSelenium

Comment: And without setting any EnvVar/Path or any dependency per se?

Comment: That's correct. It will all be handled by the library Selenium Manager packaged within selenium version 4.6.0 and above. The fact that you are so curiously asking is making me rethink. :) However am certain about what I have mentioned. I am 100% sure the above code in my answer worked without System.setProperty :)

Comment: Great point :) well we are still struggling to keep up the show with the initial support of _Selenium Manager_. Brownie points on your way ;)

Comment: I tried to remove it after dragging the chrome driver to the project and the program worked, but I still got the connection exceptions though, so I guess there is something wrong on my computer side

Answer (score 0):

### java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

[java.net.SocketException](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-net-socketexception-in-java-with-examples/) may occur due to several possible reasons as follows:

- It can occur on the server-side when the client closed the socket connection before the response could be returned over the socket. For example, by quitting the browser before the response was retrieved.
- It can also occur by writing to a connection that the other end has already closed normally resulting in an application protocol error.

---

### This usecase

I took your program and executed it. Here is the result:

- Code block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/Fishsticks");
  WebElement words = driver.findElement(By.className("words"));
  final List<WebElement> wordList = words.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
  wordList.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word.getText()));
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  batter
  cod
  united kingdom
  ketchup
  herring
  whitefish
  hake
  haddock
  pollock
  refrigerator
  british english
  breaded
  american english
  europe
  food processing
  supermarket
  grilling
  tartar sauce
  fish
  machine
  backbone
  parents
  frozen food
  wheel
  blade
  television commercial
  southampton
  shallow frying
  skin
  breadcrumbs
  salmon
  bone
  deep frying
  world war ii
  gorton's of gloucester
  clarence birdseye
  store brand
  vegetable oil
  ```

---

### Conclusion

Programmatically, I don't see any error in your code block. However ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u351](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 4.8.0](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v109.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=109.0.5414.74/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=109.0* (as per [chromedriver=109.0.5414.74 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/notes.txt)).
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium shows java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354459/7429447)
- [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62929/7429447)
- [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/585599/7429447)

Comment: I downloaded JDK 8u351, and when I check for java installations on my pc I got these:

- Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 351
- Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 333
- Java(TM) SE Development Kit 18.0.2.1 Update 351
- Java 8 Update 351

Which of these can I uninstall to have only the latest? @undetected

Comment: _JDK 8u351_ is the latest, even though _JDK 8u333_ would also suffice.