# JAVA + SpringBoot + Selenium Automation

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

When I run the project everything goes just fine, but in the middle of the test the browser closes itself and console throws me the following error

```
2023-06-14T15:27:44.720-03:00  WARN 10544 --- [cHttpClient-1-4] o.a.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler       : onError

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:256) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-06-14T15:27:44.736-03:00  WARN 10544 --- [cHttpClient-1-4] o.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket  : Connection reset

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:256) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Tried changing the network adapter config goint to Internet Protocol 4 and specifying a DNS preferred adress. Then running cmd and using ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset

Still does not work

JUnit tells me that the line where the error happens is in this method

```
public void fillForm(String nombre, String email, String asunto, String mensaje) throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement nombreInput = driver.findElement(By.name("your-name"));  
    nombreInput.sendKeys(nombre);
    WebElement emailInput = driver.findElement(By.name("your-email"));
    emailInput.sendKeys(email);
    WebElement asuntoInput = driver.findElement(By.name("your-subject"));
    asuntoInput.sendKeys(asunto);
    WebElement mensajeInput = driver.findElement(By.name("your-message"));
    mensajeInput.sendKeys(mensaje);
```

Comment: Can you post a little code snippet where the error occurs?

Comment: @M.Rogers yes, i have just done it!!! there it is

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
2023-06-14T15:27:44.720-03:00  WARN 10544 --- [cHttpClient-1-4] o.a.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler       : onError
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

...implies that [SocketException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303602/7429447) occured while [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) was initializing the client.

---

### java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

[java.net.SocketException](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-net-socketexception-in-java-with-examples/) may occur due to several possible reasons as follows:

- It can occur on the server-side when the client closed the socket connection before the response could be returned over the socket. For example, by quitting the browser before the response was retrieved.
- It can also occur by writing to a connection that the other end has already closed normally resulting in an application protocol error.

But in majority of the cases using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) the main reason seems to *incorrect libraries* being added/used.

---

### Solution

To get rid of this issue remove all the jars/libraries and download latest stable [**selenium-server-4.10.0.jar**](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/), add to your project and execute your test.

Sample Code:

```
package Day1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class genericTestFirefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 15, 2023 1:44:30 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```